# Unable to find cause of error "Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android

I am receiving the error message:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.cafeteriajava, PID: 6746
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.cafeteriajava.listener.ICartLoadListener.onCartLoadFailed(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

in CartFragment:

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements ICartLoadListener {

    private FragmentCartBinding binding;
    private ICartLoadListener cartLoadListener;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(MyUpdateCartEvent.class))
            EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(MyUpdateCartEvent.class);
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN, sticky = true)
    public void onUpdateCart(MyUpdateCartEvent event) {
        loadCartFromFirebase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cartLoadListener = this; // Initialize cartLoadListener after binding
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        init(); // Call your initialization method after binding views
    }

    private void loadCartFromFirebase() {
        List<CartModel> cartModels = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Cart")
                .child("UNIQUE_USER_ID")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot cartSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                CartModel cartModel = cartSnapshot.getValue(CartModel.class);
                                cartModel.setKey(cartSnapshot.getKey());
                                cartModels.add(cartModel);
                            }
                            if (cartLoadListener != null) { // Check for null
                                cartLoadListener.onCartLoadSuccess(cartModels);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (cartLoadListener != null) { // Check for null
                                cartLoadListener.onCartLoadFailed("Cart empty");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        if (cartLoadListener != null) { // Check for null
                            cartLoadListener.onCartLoadFailed(error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void init() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext());
        binding.recyclerCart.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.recyclerCart.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadSuccess(List<CartModel> cartModelList) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (CartModel cartModel : cartModelList) {
            sum += cartModel.getTotalPrice();
        }

        if (getContext() != null && binding != null && binding.txtTotal != null) { // Check for null
            binding.txtTotal.setText(new StringBuilder("₪").append(sum));
        } else {
            // Handle the case when context, binding, or txtTotal is null
        }

        // Check if the fragment is attached to an activity
        if (isAdded()) {
            // Pass the activity context as the first parameter
            MyCartAdapter adapter = new MyCartAdapter(requireActivity(), cartModelList);
            binding.recyclerCart.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the fragment is not attached to an activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadFailed(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(binding.mainLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have tried to move
`cartLoadListener = this;`
between OnCreate and OnViewCreated and while eventually I was able to get the app to open, whenever I tried to add a product to the cart it would crash.
Initially I recieved the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.cafeteriajava, PID: 31522
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.cafeteriajava.listener.ICartLoadListener.onCartLoadSuccess(java.util.List)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If it crash when you add product to the cart, problem might be on;

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN, sticky = true)
    public void onUpdateCart(MyUpdateCartEvent event) {
        loadCartFromFirebase();
    }
```

probably on `loadCartFromFirebase();`

you made `cartLoadListener = this;` on onCreate method, i would check the fragment life cycle and make sure onCreate called first.